# copy Address of Primary Registrant to Additional Registrants

Tags: civievent, profile

I am once again working on an event registration for an annual convention. I'd like to kno, and searching has thus far yielded nothing, is it possible to copy the first registrant's address to subsequent registrants? We often have families registering their additional household members and duplication of data entry is often cited as an annoyance. Thanks in advance.

Rachel

Comment: I wonder if you could use webform civicrm and this discussion (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219294/how-to-set-a-conditional-webform-to-copy-the-value-of-a-field-to-another) to register multiple participants

Answer (score 0):

You can share address between contacts. You can use civicrm_address.master_id to store the parent address id programatically or through UI by adding/updating address and selecting 'Use another contact's address'.

Comment: I might not have been clear. What I'm hoping to accomplish is: user enters first registrant and has selected that they are registering more than one person for the event. Registrant continues to the next registrant's screen. I'd like the address fields to pre-populate with what the first contact entered. If you're saying I could add a checkbox that lets the user say the secon address is the same as the first, then this answer makes sense. Otherwise, I'm confused how to add this option for unauthenticated visitors.